# Execute script or process right before kernel kills app with OOM

Tags: linux, go, out-of-memory

Is there a way to run a script right before a process is killed for OOM?

My go process is slowly accumulating memory and eventually the kernel kills it because the host is going out of memory.

The process exposes pprof metrics over an http socket, and the script I want to run would `curl` to that socket and save the pprof memory information.

That way I have a base for debugging *why* the process goes out of memory, as recommended in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3421#issuecomment-595861352).

**More info:**

The error:

```
Out of memory: Killed process 9421 (process_name) total-vm:10185280kB, anon-rss:6358304kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:994 pgtables:12884kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I know the kill signal is kernel-only, so my process cannot subscribe to that, but is there another signal I should be looking into? Or might the best course of action be to poll the localhost pprof URL at regular time intervals?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are out of memory, you are unlikely to be able to start another process at that moment, that is why the kernel is killing your process in the first place.

Comment: Consider just saving profiles with some frequency. Having profiles of different ages is useful anyway, because then you can [compare](https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/master/doc/README.md#comparing-profiles) them and see clearly how the memory consumption changed over time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to run a script right before a process is killed for OOM?

No.